# CSS border-width render issue

Tags: css, border

I'm new to html and css, I have confusion of how Chrome calculate **border-width** with Chrome zoom and Window scale.

**Chrome Version 114.0.5735.133 (Official Build) (64-bit)**
`border-width : 7px` . Chrome zoom : 100% . Window scale : 125%
-> computed `border-width : 6.4px`

Is there any formula for this result? Thank you!

P/S : I know that set **Window scale to 100%** or `border-box` : `box-sizing` can solve this inconsistency, I'm just be curios.

Comment: You sure that border width isn't 8px? If it's 8, it makes perfect sense, since the border width / window scale is 6.4. (8 / 1.25 = 6.4). In other words, Chrome renders the border at 6.4px wide so the resulting width is upscaled to 8px.

Comment: I'm sure I specified 7px. If I modify to 8px, it renders 8px of border-width. And modifying to 9px lead to rendering 8.800px of border-width. I tried 7/1.25 and led to this confusion.